# How to define Path for Azure Blob Storage trigger in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to trigger Azure Function without defined concrete container?

I'm expecting, that function below will be triggered for any file in any container. Name of file and container should be in variables.

```
*****function.json:
{
 "bindings": [
   {
    "type": "blobTrigger",
    "name": "myBlob",
    "path": "{container}/{name}",
    "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
    "direction": "in"
   }
],
 "disabled": false
}

*****run.csx:
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, string container, TraceWriter log, out string outputSbMsg)
{
    log.Info("C# Blob trigger function Processed blob");
    log.Info(name);
    log.Info(container);      
}
```

However, nothing is triggered. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: We tried to do the same thing and had the exact same result as you for what it's worth. We ended up having several triggers which just differ on the 'container' part. What we did to slightly mitigate the copy-pasting was to have some shared code between the triggers.

Comment: Do you have any updates about this thread?

Comment: I have postpone implementation on our side but I like idea in issue 779.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to trigger Azure Function without defined concrete container?

I assume that there is no way to trigger Azure Function without defined concrete container currently. From the Azure Function [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#storage-blob-trigger), we could use the Azure storage blob trigger to moniter a storage container.

> The Azure Storage blob trigger lets you monitor a storage container for new and updated blobs and run your function code when changes are detected

Base on my experience, we need to create multiple Azure functions to monitor the blobs as a work-around.

**Update:**

As mathewec mentioned it is an opened [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/779), more details please refer to it.

Comment: Correct - a container is required. Feel free to update your answer to state this. We have a few existing issues in our repo related to this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/779) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/572).